# Selecting Top N Column Values per Row from a data frame

Tags: r

My Data has the following form:

```
Individual Year    X2011Int    X2010Int    X2009Int   X2008Int   X2007Int
  1     2011    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
  2     2010    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
  3     2009    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
  4     2008    10.36703    18.07049    4789.338   51.3443    423.235
```

Where the X2009Int, X2008Int, X2007Int columns represent the severity of a particular event at those specified time periods. My aim is to create a function which I can loop across columns to create the following:

```
Individual   Year            T        T-1           T-2
1             2011     =X2011Int   =X2010Int    =X2009Int
2             2010     =X2010Int   =X2009Int    =X2008Int
3             2009     =X2009Int   =X2008Int    =X2007Int
4             2008     =X2008Int   =X2007Int    =X2006Int
```

To further illustrate what's going on take Individual 3 in Year 2009. Under the $T column I would need the event intensity value in X2009Int , $T-1 column = value from X2008Int, $T-2 = X2007Int, $T-3 = X2006Int, etc. (Years range from 2012-1980)

The sticking point is in my loop:

```
for(i in unique(d1$Year)){
print(i)
d1$T[d1$Year == i]     <- TOY2[TOY2$Year == i,colnames(TOY2) == i] #placed  the i value in the T column. 
d1$T.1[d1$Year == (i-1)] <- TOY2[TOY2$Year == (i-1),colnames(TOY2) == (i-1)]  
d1$T.2[d1$Year == i-2] <- TOY2[TOY2$Year == i-2,colnames(TOY2) == i-2] 
d1$T.3[d1$Year == i-3] <- TOY2[TOY2$Year == i-3,colnames(TOY2) == i-3] 

}
```

The first iteration (`$T`) column works fine but then does not perform as expected after (ie. the wrong values from my original dataframe are being pasted into the columns)

A second question is whether I would be able to perform this same task using `lapply` and if so how?

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: > `dput(head(TOY2))`

```
structure(list(Individual = 1201:1206, Wave = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L), Country = c(32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), Year = c(2011, 
2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011), `2000` = c(45.19665424, 45.19665424, 
45.19665424, 45.19665424, 45.19665424, 45.19665424), `2001` = c(176.2932337, 
176.2932337, 176.2932337, 176.2932337, 176.2932337, 176.2932337
), `2002` = c(9.601447666, 9.601447666, 9.601447666, 9.601447666, 
9.601447666, 9.601447666), `2003` = c(259.2992188, 259.2992188, 
259.2992188, 259.2992188, 259.2992188, 259.2992188), `2004` = c(4.357976722, 
4.357976722, 4.357976722, 4.357976722, 4.357976722, 4.357976722
), `2005` = c(1.955436508, 1.955436508, 1.955436508, 1.955436508, 
1.955436508, 1.955436508), `2006` = c(1.865651073, 1.865651073, 
1.865651073, 1.865651073, 1.865651073, 1.865651073), `2007` = c(61.65472296, 
61.65472296, 61.65472296, 61.65472296, 61.65472296, 61.65472296
), `2008` = c(34.62974414, 34.62974414, 34.62974414, 34.62974414, 
34.62974414, 34.62974414), `2009` = c(32.96903414, 32.96903414, 
32.96903414, 32.96903414, 32.96903414, 32.96903414), `2010` = c(6.761739867, 
6.761739867, 6.761739867, 6.761739867, 6.761739867, 6.761739867
), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2012` = c(12.05299366, 12.05299366, 
12.05299366, 12.05299366, 12.05299366, 12.05299366)), .Names = c("Individual", 
"Wave", "Country", "Year", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012"
 ), row.names = 1201:1206, class = "data.frame")
```

The first row of the expected dataframe `d1` should look like:

```
   Individual Wave Country  Year  T    T.1       T.2        T.3
      1201       6    32    2011  0  6.76174   32.96903   34.62974
```

The `T` value corresponds to the `$2011` value in the original `TOY2` df.
The `T-1` value corresponds to the `$2010` value in `TOY2`
The `T-2` value corresponds to the `$2009` value in `TOY2`
etc.

Comment: provide `dput(head(yourData))` in your post so we can easily copy it

Comment: @Recon93 Just to confirm, could you include your expected output based on your provided input.

Comment: @steveb edited, please let me know if the expected output is unclear!

Comment: I am thinking, it may be worth modifying the title of this post to more closely capture what is being solved.  Otherwise this question / answer will likely not be found in a search.  Admittedly, it is a bit hard to capture this task in a title.

Comment: @steveb Yep good idea, I'll change it!

Comment: @Recon93 In your case you are actually capturing the columns with the top 4 values less than some value (Year); in other words, the values from a different column subset per row. This column subset is captured along with the non-year columns.  Perhaps the title should reflect that.

Comment: @steveb Yes true. I'm open to suggestions but I'm not sure if my R jargon is good enough to properly encapsulate the scope of the task. So by all means, please suggest a title!

Comment: Perhaps something like "Selecting Top N Column Values per Row from a data frame" ?  I hope someone else can suggest a better title.  This at least doesn't assume a package like `dplyr`, `data.table`, base R, etc.

Comment: @steveb let's go with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a `reshape` using melt (wide to long) with `aggregate`. Below uses your `dput(head(TOY2))`:

```
library(reshape2)

mdf <- melt(TOY2, id.vars=c("Individual", "Wave", "Country", "Year"))
mdf$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(mdf$variable))  # CONVERT TO NUMERIC

# CREATE T COLUMNS
for(i in 0:11){
  mdf[paste0('T-', i)] <- ifelse((mdf$Year - mdf$variable == i), mdf$value, 0)
}

mdf$variable <- NULL    # REMOVE MELT COLS
mdf$value <- NULL       # REMOVE MELT COLS
aggdf <- aggregate(. ~ Individual + Wave + Country + Year, mdf, FUN=max)

#   Individual Wave Country Year T-0     T-1      T-2      T-3      T-4      T-5
# 1       1201    6      32 2011   0 6.76174 32.96903 34.62974 61.65472 1.865651
# 2       1202    6      32 2011   0 6.76174 32.96903 34.62974 61.65472 1.865651
# 3       1203    6      32 2011   0 6.76174 32.96903 34.62974 61.65472 1.865651
# 4       1204    6      32 2011   0 6.76174 32.96903 34.62974 61.65472 1.865651
# 5       1205    6      32 2011   0 6.76174 32.96903 34.62974 61.65472 1.865651
# 6       1206    6      32 2011   0 6.76174 32.96903 34.62974 61.65472 1.865651
#        T-6      T-7      T-8      T-9     T-10     T-11
# 1 1.955437 4.357977 259.2992 9.601448 176.2932 45.19665
# 2 1.955437 4.357977 259.2992 9.601448 176.2932 45.19665
# 3 1.955437 4.357977 259.2992 9.601448 176.2932 45.19665
# 4 1.955437 4.357977 259.2992 9.601448 176.2932 45.19665
# 5 1.955437 4.357977 259.2992 9.601448 176.2932 45.19665
# 6 1.955437 4.357977 259.2992 9.601448 176.2932 45.19665
```

Comment: Wow this is also a great solution! It's very clean :)

Comment: I believe this is the superior solution.
Just a note I had to add `mdf$Year <- as.numeric(as.character(mdf$Year))` to ensure these were numeric as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you are asking, the following hack below (using `dplyr` and `tidyr`) should work.  I changed your example input for `d1` to use a different value for each `Year`.  I believe this shows better what you want (assuming I am correctly interpreting your question).

**NOTE:** This provides an alternative approach to what the OP was attempting to do, and assumes an `lapply` solution is not necessary.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

### NOTE: the 'Year' has been modified from the OP.
d1 <- structure(list(Individual = 1201:1206, Wave = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L), Country = c(32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L), Year = c(2012, 
2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007), `2000` = c(45.19665424, 45.19665424, 
45.19665424, 45.19665424, 45.19665424, 45.19665424), `2001` = c(176.2932337, 
176.2932337, 176.2932337, 176.2932337, 176.2932337, 176.2932337
), `2002` = c(9.601447666, 9.601447666, 9.601447666, 9.601447666, 
9.601447666, 9.601447666), `2003` = c(259.2992188, 259.2992188, 
259.2992188, 259.2992188, 259.2992188, 259.2992188), `2004` = c(4.357976722, 
4.357976722, 4.357976722, 4.357976722, 4.357976722, 4.357976722
), `2005` = c(1.955436508, 1.955436508, 1.955436508, 1.955436508, 
1.955436508, 1.955436508), `2006` = c(1.865651073, 1.865651073, 
1.865651073, 1.865651073, 1.865651073, 1.865651073), `2007` = c(61.65472296, 
61.65472296, 61.65472296, 61.65472296, 61.65472296, 61.65472296
), `2008` = c(34.62974414, 34.62974414, 34.62974414, 34.62974414, 
34.62974414, 34.62974414), `2009` = c(32.96903414, 32.96903414, 
32.96903414, 32.96903414, 32.96903414, 32.96903414), `2010` = c(6.761739867, 
6.761739867, 6.761739867, 6.761739867, 6.761739867, 6.761739867
), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2012` = c(12.05299366, 12.05299366, 
12.05299366, 12.05299366, 12.05299366, 12.05299366)), .Names = c("Individual", 
"Wave", "Country", "Year", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012"
 ), row.names = 1201:1206, class = "data.frame")

d2 <-
  d1 %>%
  gather(col_year, col_val, -c(Individual:Year)) %>% # Change from wide to deep format
  filter(col_year <= Year)                       %>% # Only need rows <= Year
  group_by(Individual)                           %>%
  arrange(Individual, desc(col_year))            %>% # Sort to create ordered years per Individual
  mutate(rn = row_number()-1, new_col = ifelse(rn==0, 'T', paste0('T.', rn))) %>% # Number rows
  filter(rn < 4)                                 %>% # Keep top 4 rows
  ungroup                                        %>% # remove grouping
  select(-rn, -col_year)                         %>% # Remove un-needed columns
  spread(new_col, col_val)                           # Reformat results in wide format using new col name.
d2

Source: local data frame [6 x 8]

##   Individual  Wave Country  Year        T       T.1       T.2       T.3
##        <int> <int>   <int> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1       1201     6      32  2012 12.05299  0.000000  6.761740 32.969034
## 2       1202     6      32  2011  0.00000  6.761740 32.969034 34.629744
## 3       1203     6      32  2010  6.76174 32.969034 34.629744 61.654723
## 4       1204     6      32  2009 32.96903 34.629744 61.654723  1.865651
## 5       1205     6      32  2008 34.62974 61.654723  1.865651  1.955437
## 6       1206     6      32  2007 61.65472  1.865651  1.955437  4.357977
```

There may be a simpler way but this appears to work.

Comment: What an interesting solution! This does appear to work (will test now) but do you mind if I leave this open to possibly allow for a variation of answers? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Recon93 It is absolutely fine to leave it open so you can accept what you find to be the best answer.  If you are not familiar with `dplyr` and/or `tidyr`, the answer may need more clarification.  Let me know if you feel more explanation is needed/desired.

Comment: I've run into an error with the code: `Error in enc2utf8(col_names(col_labels, sep = sep)) : 
  argumemt is not a character vector`.

Comment: I've attempted to change all `factors` into `characters` using: `i <- sapply(d1, is.factor)
d1[i] <- lapply(d1[i], as.character)`. Does your initial code require all column names to be only `characters` (and not integers, factors, etc)?

Comment: Can you provide the input that causes the issue in the original post ?  It will be easier to see what is going on.  The solution will sort by `Individual` and the column that had a year value (e.g. 2000, 2001, etc.).

Comment: If your input columns are like `X2011Int` that would cause an issue.  The input you provided with `dput` uses year numbers (2000, 2001, etc.).  In order to use the columns `X2011Int` as `2011`, you will have to rename those columns.  The assumption I used is that the column name has the year in it, which is used for filtering.

Comment: I apologise I had made a silly error in my code. It works perfectly now! I'm very appreciative of the time you've spent helping!!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example of matrix subsetting.

```
col_index <- match(toy$year, names(toy))
toy$T_0 <- toy[cbind(1:nrow(toy), col_index - 0)]
```

Now we can place this in a function

```
val_find <- function(ind) {
  col_index <- match(toy$year, names(toy))
  toy[cbind(1:nrow(toy), col_index - ind)]
}

toy[,paste0("T_", 0:8)] <- sapply(0:8, val_find)
```

#### Example data

```
id <- 1:12
wave <- 6
country <- gl(3, 4, labels=LETTERS[1:3])
year <- rep(c(2011,2012,2010), each=4)
dates <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(1:144, 12, 12)), as.character(2001:2012))
toy <- cbind(id, wave, country, year, dates)

#Try function
toy[,paste0("T_", 0:8)] <- sapply(0:8, val_find)
toy
# id wave country year 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 T_0 T_1 T_2 T_3 T_4 T_5 T_6 T_7
#  1   1    6       A 2011    1   13   25   37   49   61   73   85   97  109  121  133 121 109  97  85  73  61  49  37
#  2   2    6       A 2011    2   14   26   38   50   62   74   86   98  110  122  134 122 110  98  86  74  62  50  38
#  3   3    6       A 2011    3   15   27   39   51   63   75   87   99  111  123  135 123 111  99  87  75  63  51  39
#  4   4    6       A 2011    4   16   28   40   52   64   76   88  100  112  124  136 124 112 100  88  76  64  52  40
#  5   5    6       B 2012    5   17   29   41   53   65   77   89  101  113  125  137 137 125 113 101  89  77  65  53
#  6   6    6       B 2012    6   18   30   42   54   66   78   90  102  114  126  138 138 126 114 102  90  78  66  54
#  7   7    6       B 2012    7   19   31   43   55   67   79   91  103  115  127  139 139 127 115 103  91  79  67  55
#  8   8    6       B 2012    8   20   32   44   56   68   80   92  104  116  128  140 140 128 116 104  92  80  68  56
#  9   9    6       C 2010    9   21   33   45   57   69   81   93  105  117  129  141 117 105  93  81  69  57  45  33
#  10 10    6       C 2010   10   22   34   46   58   70   82   94  106  118  130  142 118 106  94  82  70  58  46  34
#  11 11    6       C 2010   11   23   35   47   59   71   83   95  107  119  131  143 119 107  95  83  71  59  47  35
#  12 12    6       C 2010   12   24   36   48   60   72   84   96  108  120  132  144 120 108  96  84  72  60  48  36
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's quite neat! :)